# Change "Loading ad" text in jwplayer 6.0

Tags: video, jwplayer, jwplayer6

How cant I change the text: "Loading ad" in the control bar when preparing load ads?
I want to change this text for globalization in my country.

[image]

- In html5 player, i found this text to change.
- But in flash mode, i can't find where it be located

Comment: I'm afraid that there is no built in configuration option to change this text.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer: So can't change this text??

Comment: Not in JW6, since it is hard coded. In JW7, this can be changed easily though since all of the controls will be CSS.

Comment: Ok. Thank you @EthanJWPlayer. So, when JW7 release? :)

Comment: Still working on it, keep your eyes peeled :) Soon, though.

Comment: Whenever asked about my next release, I tell people it will be RSN - "real soon now." Useful acronym. ;)